# Define new theorem style in beamer

Tags: beamer, block, newtheorem

I want to define new theorem style in beamer class. I mean, I want to create a new block for the "claim"envinronment. For that, I use this command:

```
\makeatletter
\def\th@claim{%
\normalfont % body font
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=orange,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=orange!20,fg=black}
\def\inserttheoremblockenv{exampleblock}
}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{claim}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}%
```

It's perfect... until I want to have an enumerate. Then, I have green numbers (items) from example block. How can I change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The green color is defined in `example text` template. Change it to what you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\th@claim{%
\normalfont % body font
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=orange,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=orange!20,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=red}
\def\inserttheoremblockenv{exampleblock}
}
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{claim}
\newtheorem{claim}[theorem]{Claim}%

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{claim}{Claim}
Test
\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item Second
\end{enumerate}
\begin{itemize}
\item First
\item Second
\end{itemize}
\end{claim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]