# Block and theorem 'blocks' have the same color setting?

Tags: beamer, color, environments, theorems, block

I am trying to set the colour of my 'theorem' blocks in beamer. As per [this advice](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22329), I changed the `\setbeamercolor{block title}` and `\setbeamercolor{block body}` colours.

This worked but I noticed it also changed my 'definition' blocks to the same colour. Note that I am using `\begin{theorem}[Theorem name]`   and `\begin{block}{Definition}` environments for these.

Now according to [the following stack exchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33231/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-block-within-a-custom-beamer-sty-theme-file), `\setbeamercolor{block title}` ALSO is the colour template for blocks! This makes sense given the colour change of the definition blocks... But why would it be this way? How can I choose different colours for these?

My colour template code is below. If anyone can suggest alterations to allow the block colors to be set independently I would be grateful.

```
\definecolor{InvisibleRed}{rgb}{0.92, 0.9, 0.9}
\definecolor{InvisibleGreen}{rgb}{0.9, 0.92, 0.9}
\definecolor{InvisibleBlue}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.92}

\definecolor{LightBlue}{rgb}{0.4, 0.55, 0.65}

\definecolor{MediumRed}{rgb}{0.92549, 0.34509, 0.34509}
\definecolor{MediumGreen}{rgb}{0.36862, 0.66666, 0.65882}
\definecolor{MediumBlue}{rgb}{0.01176, 0.31372, 0.43529}

\definecolor{DarkBlue}{rgb}{0.05, 0.15, 0.3} 

\usecolortheme[named=DarkBlue]{structure}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=DarkBlue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=MediumBlue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=LightBlue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=MediumGreen}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=InvisibleGreen}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=MediumBlue}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=InvisibleBlue}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=MediumRed}
\setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=InvisibleRed}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this easily. They only “special blocks” as it were, are “example” and “alerted” (which you have styled already), everything else is just a “regular” block. But have you seen this posting? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355266/define-new-theorem-style-in-beamer